# will_paginate page_entries_info Multi Page HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I have a problem with the page_enteries_info of will_paginate.

```
<div class="row dt-rb">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="dataTables_info" id="DataTables_Table_0_info">
      <%= page_entries_info @activities %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap">
        <%= will_paginate @activities %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The will_paginate works fine but the page_enteries_info render : 'Multi Page HTML'

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occures if the translations in your locale-file are missing.

Just follow the instructions under https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/I18n and everything will be fine (and paginated!).